# Работа с потоками в С

Tags: c

Никак не могу подружиться с потоками и работой с ними.

По заданию, нужно написать программу(используя только fopen(),fclose(),fgetc(), fputc() ), которая посчитает, сколько раз в файле будет слово ananas(регистр не имеет значения). Ответ будет записан в тот же файл (содержание файла должно быть перезаписано). В рамках программы не разрешается использование каких-либо библиотечных функций (strlen(), strcpy(), strcmp() и т.д.).

вот содержимое файла в начале:

Bananas are edible fruits, botanically berries. In some countries, bAnAnAs used for cooking are called plantains, distinguishing them from dessert bananaS. The fruits grow in clusters hanging from the top of the plant. Almost all modern edible seedless BANANAS come from two wild species of Musa acuminata and Musa balbisiana. The scientific names of most cultivated bananas are Musa acuminata, Musa balbisiana, and Musa X paradisiaca, depending on their genomic constitution.

содержимое файла в конце:

5

Могли бы вы помочь с написанием этой программы или похожими примерами по работе с потоками.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для начала надо определиться для чего именно вы собрались использовать потоки в этой программе. Я вот например не вижу, зачем для решения данной задачи могло бы понадобится более 1 потока. И кроме того что бы создать второй поток потребуются библиотечные вызовы, а у вас запрещено все кроме работы с файлом

Comment: А вообще начните с того, что разделите работу на части. Сначала сделайте однопоточный алгоритм, решающий задачу. А потом уже можно будет думать на тем как его делить на потоки. Не надо пытаться искать решение именно похожей задачи. Отдельно решается задача, отдельно изучается работа потоков, потом полученные знания объединяются

Comment: @Mike, я практически уверен, что говоря о потоках, ТС имеет в виду streams, а не threads

Comment: Примеры можно посмотреть в известной книжке K&R (например, [тут](http://pdf.lib.vntu.edu.ua/books/2017/Kernigan_1992_271.pdf) 1.5.4 -- подсчет слов, можно взять за основу)

Answer (score 2):

Вот простой пример, как это можно сделать. Не лучший, но простой и без каких-либо функций, кроме перечисленных вами.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char ananas[6];

int checkSymbol(char c) {
    const char* search = "ANANAS";

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) ananas[i] = ananas[i + 1];

    if (c >= 'a') c -= (int)('a' - 'A');

    ananas[5] = c;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        if (ananas[i] != search[i]) return 0;

    return 1;
    }

int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("text.txt", "rt");
    int c, count = 0;

    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) count += checkSymbol(c);

    fclose(f);
    f = fopen("text.txt", "wt");
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", count);
    fclose(f);
    }
```

Comment: похоже, что Ваша программа найдет и слово "bananas".

Comment: @KoVadim Да, как у автора и задумано: для его текста надо вывести 5. Все эти 5 - бананасы...